# CustomOutInterceptor always get the instance of super class

Tags: java, log4j, cxf, log4j2, slf4j

To log SOAP request and response payloads, I've enabled the cxf logging and was using the default interceptors which works seamlessly. But client also wants to add **Transaction-ID** with in the `LoggingMessage` information. To achieve this I've created two new custom interceptors which extends the default `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor`.

For **inBounds** I overridden the method `formatLoggingMessage` and alter the message before logging into the console. This works perfect but for **outBounds** payloads instead of calling overridden method it calls the super class (LoggingOutInterceptor) method. I've checked the config several times but unable to resolve this.

Following is the code snippet.

**AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut.java**

```
public class AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut extends LoggingOutInterceptor
{

    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(LoggingMessage loggingMessage)
    {
        StringBuilder transactionId = new StringBuilder("\nTransaction-ID : ");
        transactionId.append(MDC.get("TRANSACTION_ID"));
        StringBuilder loggingMsg = new StringBuilder(loggingMessage.toString());
        int indexOfID = loggingMsg.indexOf("Address:");
        loggingMsg.insert(indexOfID-1, transactionId);
        return loggingMsg.toString();
    }
```

**cxf.xml**

```
    <bean id="loggingFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature">
        <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="logInbound" class="com.seamless.ers.interceptors.AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorIn"/>
    <bean id="logOutbound" class="com.seamless.ers.interceptors.AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut"/>
    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logInbound"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="logOutbound"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:features>
            <ref bean="loggingFeature" />
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>
```

**logs**

```
--------------------------------------
2022-09-27T14:54:56,033 INFO  [ERSWSReseller] -  Inbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 5 
<Transaction-ID> <--------- MISSING HERE
Address: http://localhost:8777/txe/reseller
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
----------------------------
ID: 5
Transaction-ID : 16a21796-0d96-4b9f-9951-fe6a877097fd <---- works for InBound
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

In the below image, we can see it's referring to the instance of super call instead of customOutInterceptor.

[image: Instance of super instead of customOutInterceptor]

Can someone please guide me, what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling cxf logs to `DEBUG` level, I came to know the interceptor was not adding to the chain, it was skipped by `bus` because I didn't method the `phase` to that interceptor. Along with the phase we also need to make sure that our interceptor must get chain before `LoggingOutInterceptor`.

By mentioning the phase it works perfectly.

**logs**

```
2022-09-27T18:43:34,993 DEBUG [ClientImpl] -  Interceptors contributed by bus: [com.seamless.ers.interceptors.AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut@68205edc, org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@2ea3817d, org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor@21977a79]

Adding interceptor com.seamless.ers.interceptors.AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut@68205edc to phase pre-stream

  setup [PolicyOutInterceptor]
  pre-logical [HolderOutInterceptor, SwAOutInterceptor, WrapperClassOutInterceptor, SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor]
  post-logical [SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor]
  prepare-send [MessageSenderInterceptor]
  pre-stream [AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut, LoggingOutInterceptor, AttachmentOutInterceptor, StaxOutInterceptor]
  write [SoapOutInterceptor]
  marshal [WrappedOutInterceptor, BareOutInterceptor]
  send [WebServiceAddressLoggingInterceptor]
```

**cxf.xml**

```
    <bean id="logOutbound" class="com.seamless.ers.interceptors.AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut">
        <constructor-arg value="pre-stream"/>
    </bean>
```

**Interceptor**

```
public class AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut extends LoggingOutInterceptor
{
    public AdaptorCXFLoggingInterceptorOut(String phase)
    {
        super(phase);
        addBefore(LoggingOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected String formatLoggingMessage(LoggingMessage loggingMessage)
    {
        StringBuilder transactionId = new StringBuilder("\nUnique-Identifier-ID : ");
        transactionId.append(MDC.get("TRANSACTION_ID"));
        StringBuilder loggingMsg = new StringBuilder(loggingMessage.toString());
        int indexOfID = loggingMsg.indexOf("Address:");
        loggingMsg.insert(indexOfID-1, transactionId);
        return loggingMsg.toString();
    }
}
```